# Trying to instantiate HashMap.Node in Java

Tags: java, hashmap

Java HashMap class has a static nested class Node

```
static class Node<K,V> implements Map.Entry<K,V>
```

I was trying to instantiate that Node class, but it seemed like I can't get it done as IDEA couldn't find any suitable option, as shown in screen shot below,

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PZqae.png)

anyone here can enlignten me about this?

Can this static nested class be instantiated, if so, how?

Comment: What is the purpose to instantiate it? Maybe better to use HashMap put method to add something into the Map

Comment: I know that HashMap.Node's constructor needs lots of arguments, but I just wonder whether it can be instantiated, grammatically

Comment: It is an internal class, that is used by HashMap to operate with values internally, encapsulated by design.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`HashMap.Node` is declared with *package private* visibility (the default visibility if `public`, `private` or `protected` is not used).

```
    static class Node<K,V> implements Map.Entry<K,V> {
```

This means that the class is only visible to classes in the same package.

See this question for more details: [What is the difference between public, protected, package-private and private in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/215497/what-is-the-difference-between-public-protected-package-private-and-private-in)

Comment: I've missed this basic rule, thanks